# Javascript: how can I improve these map functions?

Tags: javascript

I have a similar structure:

```js
const items = [
  {
    hip: 40,
    waist: 41,
    neck: 42,
    knee: 43,
    arm: 44,
    weight: 45,
  },
  {
    hip: 46,
    waist: 47,
    neck: 48,
    knee: 49,
    arm: 50,
    weight: 51,
  }
];
```

To use it in Highcharts, I need to transform in a similar:

```js
series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }, {
        name: 'Manufacturing',
        data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
    }, {
        name: 'Sales & Distribution',
        data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
    }, {
        name: 'Project Development',
        data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
    }, {
        name: 'Other',
        data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
    }],
```

So, I wrote this:

```js
const singleItem = props.items[0];

      const keys = Object.keys(singleItem);

      let singleSerie = [];

      keys.map(key => {
          let tempData = {
            name: key,
            data: []
          };
          const series = props.items.map(el => {
            return el[key]
          });
          tempData.data = series
          singleSerie.push(tempData)
          return singleSerie;
      })
```

It works, but it seems... "ugly". Is it possible to improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify to

```
const keys = Object.keys(props.items[0]);

const singleSeries = keys.map(key => {
  return {
    name: key,
    data: props.items.map(el => el[key]),
  };
});
```

When already using `map`, don't use `push`. And you can just inline the `series` expression in the data object literal.

Also you might want to hardcode the `keys`, so that you don't get back no series if the `items` array is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can map the keys to their data points.

```js
const items = [
  { hip: 40, waist: 41, neck: 42, knee: 43, arm: 44, weight: 45 },
  { hip: 46, waist: 47, neck: 48, knee: 49, arm: 50, weight: 51 }
];

const toSeries = (data) =>
  Object.keys(data?.[0]).map((name) =>
    ({ name, data: data.map(obj => obj[name]) }));

const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: { type: 'line' },
  title: { text: 'Title' },
  xAxis: { title: { text: 'X-Axis Label' } },
  yAxis: { title: { text: 'Y-Axis Label' } },
  series: toSeries(items)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/9.3.0/highcharts.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```